# How to go from sparse matrix to linear regression model (using SVD)?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, svd

I am trying to replicate the [Kosinski, Stillwell, & Graepel (2013) study](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/15/5802.full) about predicting private traits and attributes from Facebook like data for study purposes. First I have admit, however, that I am quite a newbie to data science and building prediction models in R.

My Data:

1. A sparse matrix (dim 237 x 43232) that contains 237 users and if they liked one of the 43232 fb-pages or not (indicated by 1 for liked and 0 for not-liked). The row-names contain user.ids.
2. A data.frame with columns containing the user.ids, age, gender, and several survey scores, for this example lets take the SOP2 score (optimism-pessimism score).

My goal is to predict the SOP2 score with the user likes. Kosinski et al. describe their model building in [this graphic](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/15/5802/F1.expansion.html). So far I have done a SVD using the irlab R package:

```
Comps.likes <- irlba(Likes.matrix, nu = 100, nv = 100)
```

And this is where I am stuck .. how to go on from here?

From what I assume I should get to something like this:

```
fit <- lm(SOP2 ~ Comps.likes$d, data = someDataFrame)
```

or an equivalent using the caret package.

What I am trying to figure out:

1. The step missing is how to get from the Comps.likes (SVD step) to
   the regression formula with a coefficient for each Facebook like to
   predict SOP2.
2. The step to actually predict SOP2 from a user vector
   with the likes per user.id.

Any help or hints to further resources?

Comment: The graphic mentions logistic or linear regression. Technically these two methods are similar for a special case, but they're used very differently. What exactly is your question? If it's "is this ok?", then I suggest we migrate the question to crossvalidated.com. If it's "how to do exactly this (in R)?" then we can probably talk here.

Comment: Since SOP2 would be a numeric value a linear regression (i.e. same with age) is suggested by Kosinski et al. in contrast to a categorical variable (e.g. gender) for which they use logistic regression. Therefore the question would be "how to do exactly this (in R)" in regard to the linear regression.